# Intergrate partial page load with php&ID link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, partial

I am trying to get partial page loads to work and I have it working but when I try to include a php variable it doesn't work.

The page loads without the variable ;

```
<li><a href="javascript:getContent('showproduct.php')">Die Cast</a></li>
```

But when I add a variable;

```
<li><a href="javascript:getContent('showproduct.php&amp;=1')">Die Cast</a></li>
```

It doesn't work. Am I adding it wrong?

My code is:

```
function getContent(url){

 var newUrl=window.location.pathname+"?page="+url;
 $.get(url, function(data) {
  var fileDom = $(data);
  $(".maincontainer").html(fileDom);
  history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead try to pass second parameter like below-

```
<li><a href="javascript:getContent('showproduct.php',1)">Die Cast</a></li>
```

update function like this-

```
function getContent(url,id){

 var newUrl=window.location.pathname+"?page="+url+"&id="+id;
 $.get(url, function(data) {
  var fileDom = $(data);
  $(".maincontainer").html(fileDom);
  history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
 });
}
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, that loads now but doesn't keep the variable. the `1` shows in the url but doesn't return the correct result